# UDP over IPv4 Expected Packet Transmission

Tags: udp, packet, ipv4, payload, transmission

I'm not quite understanding expected total of packets sent and was wondering if i'm on the right path. I have 4 computers, A, B, C, D and they relay the message from A, so A->B->C->D and I don't count transmitting back from D. And they have a packet loss of 3%. UDP on ipv4 and message must arrive for the expected destination

Say if i was to send 1000mb along a 350 byte payload
= 1000mb = 1024*1024*1000 bytes =
1048576000 bytes / 350 = 2995931.4286 packets sent

If i also had a 3% packet loss for every 100 packets

2995931.42857 * .03/100 = 8987.7943 packet loss

Does that mean i'd compute,

2995931.42857 + 8987.7943 * 3 for each transmission by each computer for extra resubmitted packets?

-Thanks heaps

Comment: UDP does not retry, so unless your application retransmit then the calculation does not make sense, if that's the case, failure rate affect the retransmission as well, like 10,000 packet transmitted, 300 will be re-transmitted, however, within those 300 packets, there will be 9 re-transmitted, and so on.

Comment: Retransmission included, but how would you know when to stop? When you hit one packet?

Comment: From engineering point of view, yes you can stop at 1 packet, if you are doing serious research, it has to be [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative).